# What are the pros and cons of using a ram disk for /run?

Tags: boot, filesystems, ramdisk

The `/run` file system was introduced to keep all the information related to the current boot sequence and can be reset at boot time. Having this in mind, isn't it a good idea to use a ram disk instead of a real partition on the hard disk?

Some of the pros I can think of is increased speed and less read and write cycles for the disk. And the only con I can think of would be RAM usage for systems with small amount of RAM.

Comment: isn't "/run" a *tmpfs* and therefore a "ramdisk" by definition? AFAIK, tmpfs is volatile memory, and not persistent.

Comment: I couldn't find any requirement for it being a tmpfs in Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf)

Comment: Sure, it isn't required by the FHS.  But pretty much all distros use tmpfs for `/run` out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was normally on the HDD, then it makes sense.